# Got segmentation fault on printing a String

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort, string-literals

In the following code, when I try to print a string, the error is "segmentation fault".
After calling `sort_array(str, str_tmp, N)`, `str` is `NULL`.

Why is that?

And of course this is the reason why it fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort_array(char **str, char **str_tmp, size_t N)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        size_t j = i;

        str = realloc(str, (i+1) * sizeof(char *));

        for ( ; j != 0 && strcmp(str_tmp[i], str[j-1] ) < 0; j--)
        {
             str[j] = str[j-1];
        }

        str[j] = str_tmp[i];
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *str_tmp[] = { "d", "a", "c", "b", "r", "o", "k", "f"};
    const size_t N = sizeof( str_tmp ) / sizeof( *str_tmp );
    char **str = NULL;

    sort_array(str, str_tmp, N);

    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        printf("%s ", str[n]);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str = realloc(str, (i+1) * sizeof(char *));` That changes a **local** variable. Caller does not see the change.

Comment: @Kaylum, it does not matter that I called fanction with char **str?

Comment: You have already [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027097/sort-array-with-realloc-fails) asked this. Why do you not follow the advice given there?

Comment: @Kaylum, I have to use realloc

Comment: @Kaylum, I know the with return it will work, I want that function will be void

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array with realloc fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027097/sort-array-with-realloc-fails)

Comment: @FelixK Ok, but if that is important then you should post it as part of the question. Otherwise you may just get the same answer again. And no, doesn't matter what type the function param is, any changes to it will never be seen by the caller. You need to dereference the pointer to be able to change the caller's value.

Comment: Is `str_tmp` supposed to be an array of characters or an array of strings? Why is `str_tmp` a `char **` (pointer to pointer to character) in `sort_array`? Some comments explaining these perplexing decisions would be helpful. If you fix these broken things, you will get compiler errors that will point you *right* to the issue. Fix the obviously broken stuff first!

Comment: @David, instead of chars it can be strings like "aaa", "bbb", etc...

Comment: @FelixK Ahh, I see now. The complete lack of comments, lack of descriptive names and use of only characters in the example caused me to completely misunderstand what your code was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the pointer `str` by reference. Otherwise the function deals with a copy of the pointer. That is the original pointer stays unchanged.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort_array(char ***str, char **str_tmp, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t j = i;

        *str = realloc(*str, (i+1) * sizeof(char *));

        for ( ; j != 0 && strcmp(str_tmp[i],( *str )[j-1] ) < 0; j--)
        {
             ( *str )[j] = ( *str )[j-1];
        }

        ( *str )[j] = str_tmp[i];
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *str_tmp[] = { "d", "a", "c", "b", "r", "o", "k", "f"};
    const size_t N = sizeof( str_tmp ) / sizeof( *str_tmp );
    char **str = NULL;

    sort_array(&str, str_tmp, N);

    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        printf("%s ", str[n]);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a b c d f k o r
```